# How to return null in Array.reduce()?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array which could looks like this. It's an array of dynamic length containing either a string or object.

```
['h', 'e', {apple: 2}, 'l', 'p']
```

I need to turn it into this:

```
 [null, null, 'apple', 'apple', null, null]
```

So I was trying to use `reduce` method and started with turning strings into null.

```
.reduce(
      (acc: Array<null | string>, val) => {
        if (typeof val === "string") return acc.concat(null);
        
        return acc.concat(val)
      },
      []
    );
```

it returns back:

```
[null]
```

and I expected:

```
[null, null, {apple: 2}, null, null]
```

Performance is moderately important, is it possible to do something like this with looping over array just once without resulting to for loops?

EDIT: sorry I made a stupid mistake, seems like my library turns it into ["he", {apple:3}, "lp"].

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue: https://jsfiddle.net/50d71mn2/

Comment: You should be using `map` to arrive at `[null, null, {apple: 2}, null, null]`, not `reduce`.

Comment: @hev1 oops!! I just noticed my library is turning it into a concatenated "help" string with {apple: 3} mixed in array, got confused since I was working with two arrays. So stupid of me!

Comment: @Bergi I can't add extra items with map, {apple: 3} needs to turn into 'apple', 'apple', 'apple'

Comment: @zakaria Yes, for that you should use `flatMap`, but your question is confusing because at one point you say "*I expected: `[null, null, {apple: 2}, null, null]`*" and the other time you said "*I need to turn it into this: `[null, null, 'apple', 'apple', null, null]`*". I was only referring to the former, as your code does not appear to even attempt to achieve the latter.

Comment: @Bergi I see, diving into mdn docs of flatMap now. I'm so sorry, my post was quite confusing indeed, I should have double checked it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Array.prototype.flatMap` -

```js
const process = (t = []) =>
  t.flatMap
    ( v =>
        Object(v) === v
          ? Object
              .entries(v)
              .flatMap(([ s, n ]) => Array(n).fill(s))
          : [ null ]
    )

const data = 
  ['h', 'e', {apple: 2}, 'l', 'p']
  
const result =
  process(data)
  
console.log(JSON.stringify(result))
// [null,null,"apple","apple",null,null]
```

If the object has multiple keys, each item will be expanded -

```js
const result =
  process(['h', 'e', {apple: 2, pear: 3}, 'l', 'p', {berry: 1}])
  
console.log(JSON.stringify(result))
// [null,null,"apple","apple","pear","pear","pear",null,null,"berry"]
```

---

`Array.prototype.flatMap` is just a specialised version of `Array.prototype.reduce` -

```js
Array.prototype.flatMap = function (f, context)
{ return this.reduce
    ( (r, x) => r.concat(f.call(context, x))
    , []
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

that ?

```js
const arr = ['h', 'e', {apple: 2}, 'l', 'p']

const rep = arr.reduce((a,c)=>
  {
  if (c instanceof Object)
    {
    let pair = Object.entries(c)[0]
    for (let n=0;n<pair[1];++n) a.push(pair[0])
    }
  else a.push(null)
  return a
  },[]) 

console.log( ...rep )
```